# Reference variable have access to dynamically allocated memory

Tags: c++

I am wondering weather this is a legal or not

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int &i=*(new int(8) );
    cout<<i<<endl;
    delete &i;
    return 0;
}
```

That a reference variable is referencing a dynamically allocating memory and then we can de-allocate the memory using delete. Is this variable "i" and be reused again or what if we try to assign some value to "i".

```
i=6;
```

After de-allocating the memory.

Comment: Yes this is legal. No you cannot reuse the variable again: a reference can only be bound once.

Comment: 99.9999% of the theoretically legal programs in C++ are bad style. This is no exception.

Answer (score 1):

```
i=6;
```

You can't use `i` any more because its memory is released. This is simliar to the dangling pointer case where the pointer itself is pointing to the memory not owned by it.

Answer (score 1):

A reference is an alias to an object. After initialization it behaves exactly as if it was the name of the referenced object. In this particular case the reference is giving a name to the object that was dynamically allocated.

The code as shown is correct and guaranteed, although I'd recommend against it. After deleting the object by means of taking the address of it through the reference, you end up with a *dangling* reference, that is, a name that refers to a dead object, and deallocated memory. Any operation applied to `i` after the `delete` is bound to cause undefined behavior.

Answer (score -2):

## include

using std::cout;

using std::endl;

int main()

{

```
  int *p=new int(8);

  //p points int(8)

  cout<<"*p="<<*p<<endl;

  delete p;


  //p points null

  int i = 10;

  //p points i

  p = &i;

  cout<<"*p="<<*p<<endl;

  return 0;
```

}

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question that was asked.